# Send GIF image in mail by cron job

Tags: php, email, cron, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I want to send an email with PHP script which include a gif image in it. It executed successfully(send mail with GIF Image) when I run it via browser URL, but when I run it via cron job/ schedule task it send only the mail body without GIF image.
CODE :

```
 <?php
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
   require 'src/Exception.php';
   require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'src/SMTP.php';
   require("connectionFile.php");
   $mail = new PHPMailer(true);   
            try 
                {
                    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                 
                    $mail->isSMTP();                                     
                    $mail->Host = 'xyz.domain.com';  
                    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
                    $mail->Username = 'xyz@domain.com';                
                    $mail->Password = 'xyz';                          
                    $mail->Port = 25;                                    
                    $mail->setFrom(xyz@domain.com, 'From:test server');
                    $mail->addAddress('abc@domain.com');  
                    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
                    $mail->Subject = "TEST MAIL";
                    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('test1.gif', 'logo_2u');
                    $mail->Body    = "Dear user,<br/><br/><img src='cid:logo_2u' width='500px' height='750px'/></br></br>IT IS A TEST MAIL..<br/>";
                    $mail->send();
                    echo 'Message has been sent';
                    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
                  } 
                  catch (Exception $e) 
                    {
                        echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
                    }   
          
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that cron jobs do not set a PATH environment var by default, so I set an absolute path of image in my script. Below are the changes required :

```
$path='/var/usr/folder_name/test1.gif';
$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($path, 'logo_2u');
```